# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in maya python

Tags: python, maya, iterable, nonetype

I'm working on a python script for autodesk maya and I have a problem with the beginning of it since 3 weeks.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os.path
import ntpath

  global directory_Seqs
  global directory_Seqs_2
  global direction_0
  global listSeqOption
  direction_0 = cmds.fileDialog2(fileMode=3,dialogStyle = 1)
  directory_Seqs = os.path.join(direction_0,'03_TRAVAIL','3D','SEQ')
  directory_Seqs_2 = os.path.normpath(directory_Seqs[0])

  print directory_Seqs_2

  listSeqOption = cmds.getFileList(directory_Seqs_2)
  for seq in listSeqOption :
      seq = cmds.menuItem('listSeq', label= seq , parent="UI_SeqOptionMenu")
```

it's working on linux, but i have a failure on windows :

```
   # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable #
```

about

```
   listSeqOption
```

can someone know how to fix it ?

Comment: You don't need those `global` declarations.  Also, the code shown is not indented correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Maya is stupid about return values: if your file path is nonexistent the call to `getFileList` will return `None` instead of an empty list.  It's a good habit to write it like this:

```
   listSeqOption = cmds.getFileList(directory_Seqs_2) or []
```

which will return an empty list even if the command returns `None`. The same is true with many other commands that should return lists, particularly `ls`.